# what can be maximum value for timeout for nginix

Tags: azure, nginx, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

I was trying to increase the timeout for Nginx ingress.

```
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-connect-timeout: "180"
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-read-timeout: "180"
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-send-timeout: "180"
```

I am curious about knowing what maximum value  I can have for these timeouts.
`proxy-connect-timeout`, `proxy-read-timeout` and `proxy-send-timeout`.
I have tried to find it but not able to do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the docs [here](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_connect_timeout)

> proxy_connect_timeout
>
> Defines a timeout for establishing a connection with a proxied server.
> It should be noted that this timeout cannot usually exceed 75 seconds

Comment: but I have seen examples on GitHub they have used `1800`. FYI: https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/issues/2007